# Uploading multiple Excel files into MySQL using MVC Framework and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, circular-dependency

I would like to make an administrative (Web API) page as an addition to an existing database in MVC Framework that allows Excel data files to be imported to a database. The web application uses Entity Framework and SimpleInjector to connect to the database.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial that does something similar? I have been using this one:

http://imar.spaanjaars.com/573/aspnet-n-layered-applications-introduction-part-1

I've been working with that so far, but it's pretty different because it was designed for csv files rather than xls/xlsx (as my files are), and uses AutoMapper. Also, the project that the administrative page is in needs to reference a repository project, which in turn already references the administrative page project, which causes a circular dependency reference. Should an interface project be made to get around this?

Excel files with different kinds of data would need to be uploaded into MySQL, so would AutoMapper be necessary to differentiate between the files or would a simpler process such as this suffice?

http://www.tejaprakash.com/2013/07/importexport-ms-excel-file-data-to.html

Also, would a separate model class representing the data on each Excel sheet be needed? I have view, model, controller, repository, and service (with dependency injection using SQL Injector) classes set up, but am having trouble getting everything to interact, and am not sure how to connect to the database from the Web API page itself.

```
    public VaultDbConfiguration()
    {
        SetHistoryContext("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new VaultMySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }

    try
    {
        Vault2.Repo.EF.VaultDbConfiguration.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("An error occurred.  No data was imported.");
    }
```

Please let me know if clarification or code samples are needed.